# MAC filtering not working on 2wire 2701HG-T modem

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem

Why would mac filtering not work on a 2wire 2701HG-T modem? I've relied on mac filtering before to block intruders with other modems, but at my mom's house, she has a 2wire 2701HG-T modem, and there are a few people stealing her wifi signal. She has had her password changed a few times, but the intruders keep on coming back. Apparently they have some good god d*** software to figure out the passwords.

In an attempt to block them out of the network, I set up mac filtering on the modem, but it does not work. I've even "blocked" one of my devices, but I am able to connect, and get internet signal even after turning on and off the router, and the wifi on the device.

I don't like the way mac filtering is set up in this modem. Rather than having a single list of allowed devices, it has a list for allowed devices, and one for blocked devices, but I would be OK with that if it actually worked.

Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without actually having a 2701 in front of me (and I'm having a hard time finding an emulator) I can't say much about what's possibly wrong in the configuration. I'd speculate that you've probably got something ticked incorrectly with regards to the MAC filter settings. Usually, SOHO routers do MAC filtering in either whitelist mode *or* blacklist mode - there's really no point in combining the two. Make sure you've got the correct mode set for how you want your router to behave. Setting the whitelist option on, but only populating the blacklist (or vice-versa), is going to have no effect. (Well, it should actually prevent all devices from connecting, while the other way around would allow all. The point is, no security benefit.)

Blacklist: Allow *all devices except* those specified in the "forbidden" list. (Easier to manage, but harder to block attackers with.)

Whitelist: Allow *only* devices specified in the "permitted" list. (Preferable between the two, as it blocks unauthorized devices by default, but harder to manage especially if you commonly allow visitors onto your network.)

**In either case, you should *not* be relying on MAC filtering as a primary defense!**

Either MAC filtering mode is pretty trivial to bypass because MAC addresses are not a permanent identifier, and they're always transmitted in the clear over the air. So, anyone can change their MAC address to whatever they want as well as see the MAC addresses of any device in range.

Blacklisting is then easily bypassed by the attacker simply changing their address to anything you haven't yet blacklisted.

Whitelisting is only slightly more difficult, but still fairly simple. The attacker just waits to see the MAC addresses of whichever devices are actively talking to your Access Point, then changes their MAC to match.

Will MAC filtering prevent some drive-by attacks? Sure. But if you're facing a dedicated attacker (and it seems you are), it's not really going to stop them much.

Though you haven't mentioned it, "SSID hiding" or "disabling beacons" or "disabling SSID broadcast" is another weak security measure which not only isn't worthwhile - it should be avoided. All it does is stop your AP from advertising itself when it is idle. However, the SSID is still sent in the clear whenever it is actively communicating so attackers will still be able to capture and use it regardless. What's worse is that, since your AP isn't broadcasting its presence, your client devices then have to be configured to seek out the AP even when they may not be near it. Attackers can then use the beacons your client devices are generating to set up their own fake AP and trick your clients into connecting.

What you *should* be relying on instead is a strong encryption and authentication protocol such as the current WPA2-PSK (which uses AES-CCMP). On top of that, you should make sure that your pre-shared key (PSK, or simply your Wi-Fi network password) is reasonably long and complex so that it's not easily guessable or crackable. So long as you have a reasonably strong PSK (I suggest a minimum of 15 characters, with 3 different character types - but WPA2 supports up to 63 characters, and I do personally use all of them fully randomized) your Wi-Fi encryption/authentication should not be easily breakable in the foreseeable future. Oh, and don't even bother with WEP (horribly broken) or WPA-TKIP (also broken, but still better than WEP). If you really can't use WPA2 for whatever reason, WPA-AES is a decent fallback until you can buy a new router.

However, there is one important caveat: WPS. Wi-Fi Protected Setup is that lovely, convenient, one-button connection mode that's available on most access points today. The problem with WPS is that there is a weakness in the PIN authentication mode, which — on many, if not most, SOHO routers currently in use — allows attackers to easily crack the PIN and then authenticate through WPS. Once WPS has granted someone access, it then gives them your PSK so that their device can connect to the network normally. *Changing your PSK will not mitigate this!* An attacker can just crack WPS again (it doesn't take long) and get the new PSK. The only way to mitigate this, which is fully within your control, is to disable WPS entirely. (Some newer routers have added functionality to inhibit such attacks, but this is not something end-users can easily validate with certainty unless they're prepared to test the exploit themselves.) Unfortunately, many router manufacturers - especially on older models - have made this difficult or impossible to do. If that's the case with your router, I strongly suggest you buy a new one or consider flashing the firmware with a third-party image such as Tomato, DD-WRT, or OpenWRT.

In summary:

- **Stop relying on MAC filtering.** It's a nice security add-on, but is really easy to bypass.
- **Don't even bother hiding your SSID.** Anyone can still see it, and your clients end up being less secure when it's not broadcast.
- **Use WPA2-PSK with a strong PSK.** *This* should be your primary defense against Wi-Fi bandwidth and data thieves.
- **Disable WPS.** No matter how great your authentication & encryption is, this is an easily exploitable back-door.
- **Get a new device or firmware if you need one.** If your current router doesn't support WPA2-PSK, and/or doesn't allow you to disable WPS, it's time for an upgrade. If said router is provided by your ISP, you can always buy your own and throw it on the network behind the ISP's router. Then, make sure your router's Wi-Fi is securely configured as laid out above and disable the Wi-Fi on the ISP router.

Comment: Thanks. Using WPA2 is something I had considered, and thought my question is not really about how to keep intruders away, but about why the mac filtering may to be working, I do appreciate the long explanation on better methods of securing a network, and why other methods may fail. As for mac filtering, the options are really simple that I don't see what I may be doing wrong. I will definitely take another look with your comments in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @Buzu I wrote my answer as I did because your question is very similar to an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)". You're asking about how to fix your attempted solution (MAC filtering) when the solution itself is not going to help you solve your problem (unwanted users on the network). Regardless of whether you get MAC filtering to work, it's not an effective block on its own - and especially worthless if the attacker is able to break/obtain your network's PSK even after a change.

Comment: If attackers are cracking/obtaining your PSK even after it's changed, it means one or more of a few simple things is happening: 1. Someone's giving it to them every time. 2. Your router has a weak implementation of WPS turned on. 3. You're using WEP. 4. You're using a weak or predictable PSK. 5. (Unlikely, but included for completeness:) A system on your network is infected. Regardless of how the PSK is being cracked/broken, and I cannot emphasize this enough, **MAC filtering will not stop, or even appreciably frustrate, a dedicated attacker.**

Comment: yes, as I said, I do appreciate your answer. Changing the password was in the list of things to do. In fact, I'm setting up a long password with the recommended encryption algorithm. I ask a lot of my question on this network of sites mostly out of curiosity regarding a specific topic, that is why I wanted to know why filtering is not working, even if it won't be part of the solution. I like to satisfy my curiosity that is all. And again, I do appreciate your answer, and all the useful info you provide :D

Comment: Also, these are not dedicated attackers. They are stupid kids who just happen to have a software available that cracks the passwords. That combined with my mom's poor knowledge of security makes them seem like dedicated attackers, but they are just clicking a button, and waiting until the program gathers all the packets it needs to crack the password. The network is usually active, so they can pretty much just run their program and it will start collecting packets right away. Thanks for your help. You certainly touch on some good points.

Comment: Today I had another chance to take a look at the modem. I decided to set a new password using WPA2. The password is 40 characters long, easy to remember, but hard to guess. I plan on writing a small program to keep an eye on the network, but that is just an idea. Thanks for your input!